# Can I use multiple java versions in parallel (Centos 7)

Tags: java, java-8, java-17

On my server I have deployed application which use java 8, but now I have to deploy one more application which use java 17. Can anyone tell how can I run both java versions at same time? Is it even possible and how?

Btw I'm using Centos 7.

Answer (score 0):

You can install multiple JDK on same server and run different application with different JDK.

In command line just run the .jar file with the JVM of your choice.